# How can I separate an extrusion from the object and give it separate material?

Tags: materials, parent, extrude, linked-data

I'm really new to **Blender** and learning some basics. I have a very limited knowledge about **modifiers** and **nodes**. So is there any way to separate an extrusion from the main object and give it new color material? I already tried the **ctrl+P** multiple times and it didn't work.

There's this simple building I'm working on. I used extrude to make a door frame for it. But when I want to give the door frame a different color, the whole building changes the color. I used separation or material by selecting and using control P, but still no results.

The funny part is that I made window frames from the very same object and separated it. It works just fine. but the door! I've been searching it for a while and all the answers were like using the ctrl+P or using nodes and modifiers which is really new and confusing for me.

I left some screen shot for better understanding. <3 sorry if the question is repetitive and dumb XD
[image]

Comment: I suggest you watch a few videos on using materials in Blender. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/assignment.html#assignment) section in the Blender manual should get you started and shows that you don't need to separate parts or use modifiers or nodes to achieve waht you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> is to parent an object to another, I doubt this is what you want here? If you want to separate some faces from a mesh to make a new object you need to select them (press <kbd>L</kbd> to easily select a separate mesh within the same object) and press <kbd>P</kbd>. That said, if you want to give another material to some faces, you don't need to create a new object, just select the faces, create a new material in the *Material* panel and click on *Assign*:

[image]

Comment: omg thank you. yes I already knew this one and simply forgot it. Thanks it worked.